# Why am I not getting a stack overflow?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, stack-overflow

**EDIT** Before you got excited see important edits in the end and if you're still curious these are reported as:

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=696222
- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=696263

---

I have been trying a piece of code and surprised to see that I didn't get a stackoverflow. Trying to simplify things I even got this far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    /* 1,500,000,000 x 4 bytes = 6,000,000,000 bytes = 6GB */
    int size = 1500000000;
    int arr[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }
    printf("first: %d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("last:  %d\n", arr[size - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

which made me doubt that I don't even know the basics of memory management. I was thinking `arr[size]` should allocate on stack and overflow easily but instead it it uses all my memory and swap and finishes successfully. What am I missing?

### Notes

- I'm running on 64 bit ubuntu 12.04
- I have tried with `gcc` and `clang` with versions:

  ```
  gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
  Ubuntu clang version 3.0-6ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)
  ```
- I have turned the optimizations off (`-O0`)
- Running `ulimit -a` I get:

  ```
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  pending signals                 (-i) 29569
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  open files                      (-n) 1024
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 29569
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited
  ```
- I have `4GB` of ram and about the same amount of swap

---

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004f4 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004004f5 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004004f8 <+4>:     push   %rbx
   0x00000000004004f9 <+5>:     sub    $0x38,%rsp
   0x00000000004004fd <+9>:     mov    %rsp,%rax
   0x0000000000400500 <+12>:    mov    %rax,%rbx
   0x0000000000400503 <+15>:    movl   $0x59682f00,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x000000000040050a <+22>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040050d <+25>:    movslq %eax,%rdx
   0x0000000000400510 <+28>:    sub    $0x1,%rdx
   0x0000000000400514 <+32>:    mov    %rdx,-0x28(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400518 <+36>:    cltq
   0x000000000040051a <+38>:    shl    $0x2,%rax
   0x000000000040051e <+42>:    lea    0xf(%rax),%rdx
   0x0000000000400522 <+46>:    mov    $0x10,%eax
   0x0000000000400527 <+51>:    sub    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000040052b <+55>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x000000000040052e <+58>:    movq   $0x10,-0x38(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400536 <+66>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x000000000040053b <+71>:    divq   -0x38(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053f <+75>:    imul   $0x10,%rax,%rax
   0x0000000000400543 <+79>:    sub    %rax,%rsp
   0x0000000000400546 <+82>:    mov    %rsp,%rax
   0x0000000000400549 <+85>:    add    $0xf,%rax
   0x000000000040054d <+89>:    shr    $0x4,%rax
   0x0000000000400551 <+93>:    shl    $0x4,%rax
   0x0000000000400555 <+97>:    mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400559 <+101>:   movl   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400560 <+108>:   jmp    0x400577 <main+131>
   0x0000000000400562 <+110>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400566 <+114>:   mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
   0x0000000000400569 <+117>:   movslq %edx,%rdx
   0x000000000040056c <+120>:   movl   $0x1,(%rax,%rdx,4)
   0x0000000000400573 <+127>:   addl   $0x1,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400577 <+131>:   mov    -0x18(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040057a <+134>:   cmp    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040057d <+137>:   jl     0x400562 <main+110>
   0x000000000040057f <+139>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400583 <+143>:   mov    (%rax),%edx
   0x0000000000400585 <+145>:   mov    $0x4006bc,%eax
   0x000000000040058a <+150>:   mov    %edx,%esi
   0x000000000040058c <+152>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040058f <+155>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0000000000400594 <+160>:   callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000400599 <+165>:   mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x000000000040059c <+168>:   lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
   0x000000000040059f <+171>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005a3 <+175>:   movslq %edx,%rdx
   0x00000000004005a6 <+178>:   mov    (%rax,%rdx,4),%edx
   0x00000000004005a9 <+181>:   mov    $0x4006c7,%eax
   0x00000000004005ae <+186>:   mov    %edx,%esi
   0x00000000004005b0 <+188>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004005b3 <+191>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005b8 <+196>:   callq  0x4003f0 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004005bd <+201>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005c2 <+206>:   mov    %rbx,%rsp
   0x00000000004005c5 <+209>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rbx
   0x00000000004005c9 <+213>:   leaveq
   0x00000000004005ca <+214>:   retq
End of assembler dump.
```

---

```
$ pmap 2840
2840:   ./a.out
0000000000400000      4K r-x--  /home/gokce/play/a.out
0000000000600000      4K r----  /home/gokce/play/a.out
0000000000601000      4K rw---  /home/gokce/play/a.out
00002b572d7be000    136K r-x--  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00002b572d7e0000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
00002b572d9e0000      4K r----  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00002b572d9e1000      8K rw---  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00002b572d9e3000   1748K r-x--  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
00002b572db98000   2044K -----  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
00002b572dd97000     16K r----  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
00002b572dd9b000      8K rw---  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
00002b572dd9d000     28K rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffe080a2000 5859388K rw---    [ stack ]
00007fff6dbfc000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
 total          5863408K
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

I was using a small hand written makefile:

```
build:
        gcc foo.c -Wall -Wextra -g

run:
        ./a.out

.SILENT:
```

to run the program using my common editor shotcuts and I realized now that it is somehow relevant. I got the segfault when I run from the console using:

```
./a.out
```

but not when I run with:

```
make run
```

How is that relevant?

**IMPORTANT EDIT2**

When I try to run `ulimit -s` in `make run` like:

```
build:
        gcc foo.c -Wall -Wextra -g

run:
        ulimit -s

.SILENT:
```

it gives:

```
make: ulimit: Command not found
make: *** [run] Error 127
```

then I realized it changes when I add an extra `#` in the end: (isn't it the comment character?)

```
build:
        gcc foo.c -Wall -Wextra -g

run:
        ulimit -s #

.SILENT:
```

I get:

```
unlimited
```

I also checked my bash aliases and there's no `make`. `which make` gives `/usr/bin/make` and `file /usr/bin/make` gives:

```
/usr/bin/make: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically 
linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x1d76b881b71091d
37e6653d7c8b8e19a2a414591, stripped
```

Comment: Not reproducing your absence of problem (i.e. segfaults for me).

Comment: @Mat how much ram+swap have you got? mine blows at about `1600000000` so you may try reducing just a little bit.

Comment: More than enough to hold that array (16G). The stack overflows unless the size of the array is less than the max stack (8M here).

Comment: @Mat what OS are you using? I'm guessing it shouldn't matter but still..

Comment: Linux (Gentoo). You're not running that as root are you?

Comment: You got 4GB RAM + 4GB swap, and you're allocating 6GB. 
With virtual memory your allocated block can be whenever, even on the disk.So try with 9 GB.

Comment: @NPE added to the question notes

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: That's not the question. OP clearly expects the VLA to go on the stack, and the array is clearly way too big to go on the stack.

Comment: @Mat nope, just regular user

Comment: @gokcehan: Why not compile the code with `-S` and include the resulting assembly source in your question. That's tell us whether the allocation happens on the stack or on the heap (my compiler allocates the VLA on the stack, and your code segfaults).

Comment: @gokcehan: One more suggestion: can you `pmap` your process while it's running and include the output in your question.

Comment: @gokcehan: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I meant run it for a while, and then `pmap` it. I want to see whether the stack actually grows past the `ulimit`.

Comment: @NPE first time using `pmap` actually. updated the question accordingly..

Comment: It's probably not gonna solve the case, but what happens if you define array in an old-fashion way, something like "int arr[NUMBER]", and then compile it with gcc requiring it *not* to support c99 standard by dding "-std=c89"?

Comment: @kliteyn I tried it, got the same result.

Comment: What I really don't understand is why you need that `#` to make `ulimit -s` work from your `Makefile`. This may sound inconsequential, but it really bothers me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr` is clearly getting allocated on the stack, as you'd expect. From the `pmap` output, the stack is clearly growing to nearly 6GB:

```
00007ffe080a2000 5859388K rw---    [ stack ]
```

The question is therefore not about your program or the compiler. The question is why `ulimit -s 8192` is apparently not being enforced.

From your answers to my various question, it is clear that somehow the `ulimit -s` setting is not being propagated from your shell through `make run` to your program. This to me seems very odd.

If I were in your shoes, I'd go through the system's `limits.conf` as well as the shared and the user's `bash` startup files to see if I can spot anything of relevance.

Comment: just to make it clear, I was running from the editor but now that I realized I tried running with `make run` from the shell and got no stack overflow. does it apply to `make` process as well?

Comment: @gokcehan: that's still strange. With your program and your `Makefile`, I get `make: *** [run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: @gokcehan: Try adding `ulimit` to your `Makefile` as suggested in my edit.

Comment: @NPE got the segfault as expected. can you reproduce the absence of segfault with makefile?

Comment: @gokcehan: I can't. What does `ulimit -s` say in the same shell where you run `make run` immediately prior to you running `make run`?

Comment: @NPE when I run `ulimit -s` from `make run` I get `make: ulimit: Command not found make: *** [run] Error 127` although I got `8192` when I run from shell.

Comment: @gokcehan: We also need to ensure that `make` is what we think it is, and not some weird wrapper or some such. Please see the questions I've added to my answer.

Comment: @NPE added the answers to your questions to the question. my previous comment has changed a little bit.

Comment: @NPE I feel like accepting this as an answer and open a new question or a bug report for the nasty make bug alike. do you think it's strange that I get `unlimited` stacksize in a make process. sounds like a security flaw to me..

Comment: @gokcehan: I suspect there's an answer somewhere on your system (maybe in `limits.conf`, maybe in a `bash` startup file...)

Comment: @NPE these turned out to be debian bug alikes (links added to the question), thanks for all the help..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't verify it, but IMHO, this is what's happening:

```
int size = 1500000000;
```

You get an overflow here - the number is too big for int.
The **actual** value for variable "size" will be much lower.
Your compiler should actually warn you about this.
Again, I didn't verify it because I'm too lazy for this.
Try this:

```
#define SIZE 1500000000ULL
int arr[SIZE];
```

And, of course, the "i < SIZE" condition also needs to be corrected - i is int, so the condition will always be true (again, compiler should warn you about this too).
Good luck.

Comment: that was one of my guesses but I tried using `long size = 1500000000` instead but got the same result.

Comment: It's easy to verify this one, one way or the other -- print out `size`.  In theory the OP's compiler should support 32-bit integers, so > 2 billion, but there could be a compiler flag requesting 16 bit ints.

Comment: Though I see the literal 59682f00 is being loaded in the disassembly, and that's 1,500,000,000.

Comment: There is no need to guess. From the machine code it's clear that nothing's been done to `1500000000`.

Comment: 1500000000 < 2**31-1, so it fits comfortably in a 32-bit `int`.